# Debian Linux can't ping gateway

Tags: linux, networking, debian, linux-networking, route

I'm having a strange networking issue where I can't ping my gateway or any machines in my lan. The request just times out. I CAN ping external hosts like google. I'm running Debian Jessie. The machine is configured with DHCP.

Here is route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use     Iface
0.0.0.0         10.200.152.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.200.152.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.200.160.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
169.254.169.254 10.200.154.6    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

Here is ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group  default
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state  UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether fa:16:3e:c9:3b:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.200.154.228/22 brd 10.200.155.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fec9:3b6e/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether fa:16:3e:64:5e:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.200.177.171/19 brd 10.200.191.255 scope global eth1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe64:5eb5/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route show dev eth0

```
default via 10.200.152.1
10.200.152.0/22  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.200.154.228
169.254.169.254 via 10.200.154.6
```

Comment: Do your LAN devices normally respond to ICMP requests? Do you see the same behaviour when testing from another device on the LAN?

Comment: Yeah, I can ping the device from another device.

Comment: Any local iptables rules which could be causing this? Can you run a packet capture on one of the internal devices you are trying to ping and see if the packets are arriving OK?

Comment: So the cause ended up being that this box was on a heavily locked down network.  The issue ended up being on the gateway side.  We moved the box do a different network.  All works now.